# Why is every thing in alpha?

Tags: light, transparency

[image][image][image]I am new in blender. so I am trying this tutorial. and when I hit render view everything is in alpha.
So I cant see my light source and everything.

I have tried multiple things like load factory settings and stuff can some one help me out?

Comment: There is nothing "in alpha". Your World is set to a grey background so this is what is visible. The grey seems to illuminate your objects as well. I can't see the settings of your lamp object and so it's hard to tell why it doesn't light your objects. Or what do you mean by saying you can't see your "light source and everything"? The light source is the dotted circles thing, your camera is that black pyramid-like outline and your object(s) is/are the dark grey column in the middle.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! what color does the background need to be? and i will ad a photo of the light settings

Comment: I know my lightsource. but is seems like it doesnt influence the object. if i say render image aswell it shows me an alpha cut out from my object.

Comment: please provide blend file